# How to handle asynchronous token renew with a nested request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm making a `POST` request in a `POST` request. The second `POST` is using a `token` from the first `POST` request.

I don't really know when the `2nd POST` will finish but I'm pretty sure it will last longer than the expiration time of the `token`, let's assume it's about `10 seconds`.

Now my issue is how do I handle it . I mean how do I renew the token knowing that it's used in the `2nd POST`.

Here is my code :

```
var request = require('request');
var async   = require('async');
var fs      = require('fs');
var renew_token_timer ;



var o = {
    "someValue": "s",
    "someValue2": "g"
};
var s = JSON.stringify(o);

request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    uri: '/getToken',
    body: s,
    method: 'POST'
}, function (err, res, body) {

    var renew_token = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("renew token now after 10sec");
    },10000);

    var token = JSON.parse(body);
    var tasks = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){
        tasks.push(function(callback){
            getPeople(25, i, token, callback);
        });
    }
    async.series(tasks,
    function(err, results) {
        console.log("FINISHED");
    });

  });

  function getContacts(pageSize, page, access_token, callback){
    var to_send = {"test" : "test"};

   var to_send = JSON.stringify(to_send);
   var url = "/getPeople";
   request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
     time : true,
     uri: url,
     body: to_send,
     method: 'POST'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        callback();
   });
  }
```

Any advice please ?

Comment: @skyboyer but when you start to retrieve a new token because the old one is deprecated, some requests might fail until the new token gets set.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this, lets extract the calls into promising functions:

```
  function retrieveToken() {
   return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    request({
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'  },
     uri: '/getToken',
     body: JSON.stringify({ "someValue": "s",  "someValue2": "g" }),
     method: 'POST'
    }, (err, _, body) => err ? rej(err) : res(JSON.parse(body)));
  });
 }

 const retrieveContacts = (size, page, token) => new Promise(res => getContacts(size, page, token, res));
```

Now it is pretty simple:

```
 (async function() {
   // Get the first token to start:
   let token = await retrieveToken();
   // Update the token sometimes:
   setInterval(async () => token = await retrieveToken(), 8000);
   // Retrieve the data
   for(let i = 1, i < 10; i++)
     await retrieveContacts(25, i, token);
 })();
```

This just updates the token variable every 10 seconds, so that it will point to a new token. This should work in most cases.

---

Now if retrieving the token takes more time than estimated, it could happen that requests take a deprecated token. To prevent this, just work with a token Promise and await it before doing a request:

```
 (async function() {
   // Get the first token to start:
   let tokenPromise = retrieveToken();
   // Update the token sometimes:
   setInterval(() => tokenPromise = retrieveToken(), 10000);
   // Retrieve the data
   for(let i = 1, i < 10; i++)
     await retrieveContacts(25, i, await tokenPromise);
 })();
```

This will wait for a new Token to come in before sending another request after the previous token deprecated.

Comment: Thanks ! what is the `getToken` ?

Comment: @AshBringer a typo :)

Comment: I have an error in ths js file, `if (!) return [3 /*break*/, 5]`, don't really where it's coming from

Comment: I don't need to modify my `getContacts` function right ?

Comment: @ashbringer no, unless you want to handle the results of the request

Comment: Well I can't understand what's the error and why it's actually doing this

Comment: @ashbringer i guess me neither. Could you show me the full error?

Comment: if (!) return [3 /*break*/, 5];
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:613:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)

Comment: I think you can reproduce it if you copy paste my `getContacts` function and the code you have posted :)

Comment: @ashbringer try to run it directly to get the real error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875059/syntax-error-at-new-script-vm-js517-whilst-running-code-for-a-discord-bot-in?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ashbringer also make sure you use a recent nodejs version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685160/syntax-error-on-async-arrow-function

Comment: I'm running node v9.8. Have you tested the code, are you getting an error as well ?